# How to efficiently iterate two files in python?

Tags: python, performance, file, duplicates

I have two text files which should have a lot of matching lines and I want to find out exactly how many lines match between the files. The problem is that both of the files are quite large (one file is about 3gb and the other is over 16gb). So obviously reading them into the system memory using read() or readlines() could be very problematic. Any tips? The code I'm writing is basically just a 2 loops and an if statement to compare them.

Comment: Are the files sorted? Can you pre-sort them if not?

Comment: @TheFoxx Will the lines to be matched appear in the same sequential order with more/less lines in between or is the order jumbled?

Comment: Open file objects are iterators; so you can call `next()` on them to get their next line. With some extra line buffers, that should make it easy to iterate over both and find matching lines.

Comment: The files being sorted doesn't particularly matter, even when sorted, the 2 lines which are next to each other in the small file could be separated by millions of lines of text in the large file.

Comment: @TheFoxx: The reason people are asking about sorting is that if the two files are sorted, you only need to keep one line from each file in memory at any given time. The potential "millions of lines" separating consecutive matches is irrelevant.

Comment: @JohnY But how do I only store a single line in the memory at any given time? Someone below mentioned using readline.() but that got downvoted?

Comment: @TheFoxx: Read one line from each file. If they're the same, that's a match; read the next line from each file. If they're different, then just read the next line from the file whose line had a lower value and compare again. Keep doing this until at least one of the files has no more lines to read.

Comment: @JohnY But how? How do I only read one line at a time without reading in the whole file into system memory?

Comment: @TheFoxx: In other words, if the files are sorted, then finding the matching lines only requires one loop, not two. (And if the files are not sorted, then it probably makes sense to sort them first.)

Comment: @TheFoxx: Martijn already told you. Use `next()`. (Or you could use `readline()`. The answer by Kowalski uses it wrong.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks all for your input! But what I ended up doing was painfully simple. I was trying things like this, which read in the whole file.

```
file = open(xxx,"r")
for line in file:
      if.....
```

What I ended up doing was

```
for line in open(xxx)
    if.....
```

The second one takes the file line by line. It's very time consuming, but I've pretty much accepted that there isn't some magically way to do this that will take very little time :(

Answer (score 2):

Since the input files are very large, if you care about performance, you should consider simply using `grep -f`.  The `-f` option reads patterns from a file, so depending on the exact semantics you're after, it may do what you need.  You probably want the `-x` option too, to take only whole-line matches.  So the whole thing in Python might look something like this:

```
child = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-xf', file1, file2], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in child.stdout:
    print line
```

Comment: This looks very interesting, could you explain what the child variable is doing? Like the subprocess.Popen bit??

Comment: I just grepping the files there in unix and I ran into memory problems again, had to kill the process before it crashed my machine.

Answer (score 1):

why not use unix `grep`? if you want your solution platform independent then this solution will not work. But in unix it works. Run this command from your python script.

```
grep --fixed-strings --file=file_B file_A > result_file
```

Also this problem seems to be a good reason to go for map-reduce.

**UPDATE 0:** To elucidate. `--fixed-strings = Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.` and `--file= Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.`

So what we ar doing is getting patterns from `file_B` matched against the content in `file_A` and `fixed-strings` treats them as a sequence of patterns the way they are in a file. Hope this makes it clearer.

Since you want the count of matching lines a slight modification of the above `grep` we get the count -

```
grep --fixed-strings --file=file_B file_A | wc -l
```

**UPDATE 1:** You could you do this. first go through each file separately line by line. dont read the entire file into memory. when you read one line compute md5 hash of this line and write it to another file. When you do this 2 both files, you get 2 new files filled with md5 hashes. I am hoping that these 2 files are substantially smaller in size the original files, since md5 is 16bytes irrespective of i/p string. Now you can probably do grep or other diffing techniques with little or no memory problem. – Srikar 3 mins ago edit

**UPDATE 2: (few days later)** Can you do this? create 2 tables `table1, table2` in mysql. Both having only 2 fields `id, data`. Insert both the files into both these tables, line by line. After which run a query to find count of duplicates. You have to go through both files. Thats given. We cant run away from that fact. Now the optimisations can be done in how dups are found. MySQL is one such option. It removes a lot of things that you need to do like RAM space, index creation etc.

Comment: I had actually considered using unix grep, but I'm a lot comfortable in python (But I really need to learn more unix!) I don't quite understand your code there, obviously file_B and file_A are my files, but I don't get the fixed strings bit?

Comment: ok, this is simple. Since you said most content in those 2 files are same. this single command finds this for you. See my updates above.

Comment: Thanks. The problem once again is memory, running this grep almost crashed my machine. I had to kill it before it actually crashed my machine.

Comment: could you do this? first go through each file separately line by line. dont read the entire file into memory. when you read one line compute md5 hash of this line and write it to another file. When you do this 2 both files, you get 2 new files filled with md5 hashes. I am hoping that these 2 files are substantially smaller in size the original files, since md5 is 16bytes irrespective of i/p string. Now you can probably do grep or other diffing techniques with little or no memory problem.

Comment: Now there's a really neat idea. It would still just be comparing two lines right? I'll try it out

Comment: yes you would be comparing 2 string but these 2 string would be md5 hashes of 16bytes in length. makes the size of the entire files a lot smaller.

Comment: A clever solution, but the time it would take to convert each file to m5d isn't practical. Thanks though!

Comment: some more needed. is this a one-off job? will this job needs to be run everyday? whats are the constraints? will the file sizes be this huge every time?